# AngularJS multidimensional arrays with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to create a multidimensional arrays that will hold 6 JSON responses. I have been looking at others for help: [multidimensional array in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271236/multidimensional-array-in-angular)

but when I test my console log for the multidimensional array I get the output "Stat array: undefined", calling just this index of the whole array returns [object Object].

```
$scope.pokeArray = new Array(11);
        $http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+searchedName +".json")
            .success(function (response)
                {
                    //Get first form FORMS array, assign name
                    $scope.pokeArray[0]  = response.forms[0].name;
                    //13 ID
                    $scope.pokeArray[1]  = response.id;
                    //10 Height
                    $scope.pokeArray[2]  = response.height;
                    //7 Sprites
                    $scope.pokeArray[3]  = response.sprites.front_default;
                    $scope.pokeArray[4]  = response.sprites.front_shiny;
                    //3 Stats 5-11
                    //Speed
                    $scope.pokeArray[5]  =  response.stats[1].base_stat;

                    //Index 6 = Array of 6
                    $scope.pokeArray[6] = [
                        {
                            speed    : response.stats[0].base_stat,
                            spDefense: response.stats[1].base_stat,
                            spAttack : response.stats[2].base_stat,
                            defense  : response.stats[3].base_stat,
                            attack   : response.stats[4].base_stat,
                            hp       : response.stats[5].base_stat
                        }];

                    console.log("Name: "  + response.forms[0].name);
                    console.log("Height: "+ response.height);
                    console.log("ID: "    + response.id);
                    console.log("Array: " + $scope.pokeArray);
                    console.log("speed: " + response.stats[1].base_stat);
                    console.log("Stat array: " + $scope.pokeArray[6].speed);
                }
            );
    }
```

As you can see, my first 5 arrays are all containing the direct responses and this works fine, I have tested it with my console logs and I have used the information in my html view.

Currently, the last console log returns "Stat array: undefined". Maybe, theres a different way I should be doing my responses in the mutlidemensional array but I'm not sure, I thought maybe if i tried to use [6][0] to get speed that could work? But this causes an error.

If anyone could tell me if it is my array, or JSON handling that is causing an issues, that would really help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Can we see the serialized value of `response`?

Comment: You get `[object Object].` because you are trying to concatenate an object with a string. When this happens the `toString()` method is called, and since your object doesnt have a custom toString method it uses the default one which gives you the object type as a string.

Comment: @PatrickEvans So, if all the data was of string type, the ToString() would be called and have no issues so the output wouldn't be [Object object]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating an array instead of creating an object, do this:

```
$scope.pokeArray[6] = {
    speed    : response.stats[0].base_stat,
    spDefense: response.stats[1].base_stat,
    spAttack : response.stats[2].base_stat,
    defense  : response.stats[3].base_stat,
    attack   : response.stats[4].base_stat,
    hp       : response.stats[5].base_stat
};
```

Comment: Nice catch.  Nested `[` and `{` brackets creating an array with a single object in it.

Comment: Thank you @Amit, so the way I should look at it is to not create an array in an index of another array, but to create multiply objects within one index.

Comment: @Tecwyn - I have no idea what you should be doing, that's up to your functional requirements, but I **do know** what you did wrong, and I showed you one way how to fix that.

Comment: @Amit It's ok I was just saying that my concept was wrong. Was looking at it incorrectly, thanks.

Comment: @Tecwyn - glad to help ;-)

Comment: @Amit Hi Amit, It seems stackoverflow doesnt allow for PMs, so I hope you dont mind me doing this as a way to ask you a questions beacuse I didnt want to start another Question. I have gone to my friend for help but we have tried a range of things but cant seem to work anything out. In an attempt to tidy up my code a little, I thought I would use a ng-repeat to go through all 6 arrays, instead of 6 sperate ones. but nothing I do can seem to output correctly. Test 1: works and outputs "Speed" but defeats the purpose as I had to specifically say "stat0Array". Test 2 is blank. I hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http){
$scope.pokeArray = new Array(11);
        $http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charmander.json")
            .success(function (response)
                {
                    //Get first form FORMS array, assign name
                    $scope.pokeArray[0]  = response.forms[0].name;
                    //13 ID
                    $scope.pokeArray[1]  = response.id;
                    //10 Height
                    $scope.pokeArray[2]  = response.height;
                    //7 Sprites
                    $scope.pokeArray[3]  = response.sprites.front_default;
                    $scope.pokeArray[4]  = response.sprites.front_shiny;
                    //3 Stats 5-11
                    //Speed
                    $scope.pokeArray[5]  =  response.stats[1].base_stat;

                    //Index 6 = Array of 6
                    $scope.pokeArray[6] = [
                        {
                            speed    : response.stats[0].base_stat,
                            spDefense: response.stats[1].base_stat,
                            spAttack : response.stats[2].base_stat,
                            defense  : response.stats[3].base_stat,
                            attack   : response.stats[4].base_stat,
                            hp       : response.stats[5].base_stat
                        }];

                    console.log("Name: "  + response.forms[0].name);
                    console.log("Height: "+ response.height);
                    console.log("ID: "    + response.id);
                    console.log("Array: " + $scope.pokeArray);
                    console.log("speed: " + response.stats[1].base_stat);
                    console.log("Stat array: " + $scope.pokeArray[6][0].speed);
                });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
{{pokeArray[6][0].speed}}

</div>
```